# Get execution ID for Google Cloud Functions triggered from PubSub event

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

For Google Cloud Functions triggered from HTTP, it is possible to retrieve the execution id by inspecting the headers of the HTTP request (`"Function-Execution-Id"`) :

```
package p

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func F(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    executionID := r.Header.Get("Function-Execution-Id")
    fmt.Println(executionID)
}
```

However, for GCF triggered by PubSub events, I can't find how to retrieve this execution ID :

```
package p

import (
    "context"
)

type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

func F(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    executionID := "" // ???
    fmt.Println(executionID)
    return nil
}
```

I have looked into the `PubSubMessage` (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage), but it only contains `data` + an empty `attributes` map.

I have also checked if execution ID is in the `metadata` handled by the context. However, from my tests, and the docs (https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata#FromContext), only `EventID`, `Timestamp`, `EventType` and `Resource` are present.

How can I retrieve the execution id of a GCF function triggered by a PubSub event?

Comment: Is there a documentation about the `Function-Execution-Id` request header? I didn't find any documentation about it after searching a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible to get execution id from pubsub triggered events.

You can get the event id from context as Lauren stated but that does *not* match execution id.

Also, pubsub triggered events *do* have execution ids.  You can see this by using a default logger to log the event id.  In stackdriver there will be an attached execution id label and it will not match the event id.  We have observed that event id is numeric while execution id is alphanumeric.

Further, if the function is retried, it will keep the same event id but get a different execution id.

This is a recent (undocumented) change but can be easily observed.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This appears to no longer be accurate. See the other answer from ProGirlXOXO.**

A Pub/Sub-triggered event does not have an execution ID; instead it has an `EventID` contained in the context metadata, which is a unique ID for the event.

You can access the `EventID` as follows:

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata"
)

func F(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    ctxMetadata, err := metadata.FromContext(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err);
    }
    log.Println("EventID: " + ctxMetadata.EventID)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, `EventID` is different from the execution ID of the Cloud Function, as we can see in Stackdriver (label `execution_id` of any log entry). This is this particular execution ID that I try to retrieve (the same contained in `Function-Execution-Id` header in HTTP functions). Is it really not possible in PubSub triggered functions?

Comment: You're correct, Pub/Sub-triggered events do actually have `execution_id` labels in the log entries. Note that the Pub/Sub-triggered event `execution_id` is a different format than the HTTP-request-triggered `execution_id`. The `EventID` in the context metadata matches the `execution_id` label.

Comment: `EventID` is different from the `execution_id` label in Stackdriver logs, I've checked it with the exact code you added, and tested it by sending a PubSub event from the *Testing* tab in the Console. They do not have the same format : `EventID` is an UUID, while `execution_id` on Stackdriver logs (in `labels` field of the log entry) is a string of alphanumeric characters (12 characters in my case, but it seems to vary from one project to another). Anyway, these are not the same IDs. Are they somehow related? How is this `execution_id` added by the Cloud Function on Stackdriver logs?

Comment: I got it; I've tried to send a message directly on the PubSub topic (**not** via the *Testing* tab in the Console), and it generates - as you said - an `EventID` matching the `execution_id` label on Stackdriver logs. Looks like testing the Cloud Function from the Console have mysterious outcome. I'm curious, do you know why I got this behaviour when sending an event from the *Testing* tab? Maybe this is because it does not send a real message to the source PubSub topic? Anyway, it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: Please mark that this answer is no longer accurate.  PubSub triggered cloud functions get an event id but that ID does not match execution id.  Event IDs are numeric while execution ids are alphanumeric.  Event ids are uniquely given to a cloud function triggered by pubsub.  If that event must be retried, it keeps the same event id but execution id changes.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO I trust you then and have accepted your answer :) Hope it can helps other people!