# Cloud Functions triggered by Cloud Pub Sub and Logs Viewer EventId Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

Since 2020-04-28, I noticed that function context.event_id is no more equals to the labels execution_id in Logs Viewer:

[image]

To reproduce the error, create a Cloud Functions triggered by Pub Sub (here with Python):

```
import logging

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    logging.info(context.event_id)
```

I expected to get an entry like this:

```
{
   "textPayload": "447023927402809",
   "insertId": "000000-599a0542-c78a-42e3-b0d0-bb455078dabf",
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_function",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
       "region": "us-central1",
       "function_name": "function-1"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-04-30T20:07:12.125Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "labels": {
     "execution_id": "447023927402809"
   },
   "logName": "projects/xxxxxxxxx/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
   "trace": "projects/xxxxxxxxx/traces/cfa595b77b16d6f27a5f77c472ed0e20",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-04-30T20:07:14.388866116Z"
 }
```

But the entry contains a different execution_id

```
{
   "textPayload": "447023927402809",
   "insertId": "000000-599a0542-c78a-42e3-b0d0-bb455078dabf",
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_function",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
       "region": "us-central1",
       "function_name": "function-1"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2020-04-30T20:07:12.125Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "labels": {
     "execution_id": "k994g1h0pte3"
   },
   "logName": "projects/xxxxxxxxx/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
   "trace": "projects/xxxxxxxxx/traces/cfa595b77b16d6f27a5f77c472ed0e20",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2020-04-30T20:07:14.388866116Z"
 }
```

Any ideas about this change? The release page doesn't contain any reference to that:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes

Thanks,

Philippe

Comment: I never thought they were supposed to match.  I've always taken execution ID to mean a specific invocation of a function, and event ID to mean a unique ID for the event that triggered the function.  Since an event can be retried, the event ID should be the same for each retry invocation, but the execution ID would be different among retries.

Comment: They probably changed the behavior because event_id was equals to execution_id at the beginning of the week. It was helpful for retrieving logs for a specific event_id.

Comment: @DougStevenson I will reformulate my question, do you know any way to get execution_id at execution runtime? Thanks

Comment: Might this post be a clue in our story ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56152806/get-execution-id-for-google-cloud-functions-triggered-from-pubsub-event

Comment: I believe this issue is asking for the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357244/how-to-group-cloud-function-log-entries-by-execution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like this is currently possible.

I've filed an issue internally requesting this feature, and will update this answer if I have updates.

Comment: Thank you @di, it's really appreciated! Regards, Philippe